# Flutter Bloc State Management: Application Stuck on Splash Screen with Route Listener

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-go-router

I have an application in Flutter that uses Bloc state management. I added a splash screen to this app, and on the splash screen, I'm using a Listener to manage routes. Unfortunately, the application gets stuck on this screen. The listener structure I check on the screen looks like this.

```
 
Future<void> initializeApp() async {
  final widgetsBinding = WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  FlutterNativeSplash.preserve(widgetsBinding: widgetsBinding);
  
  late String envFileName; 
  await dotenv.load(fileName: envFileName);
 
  await setupInjection();
 
  FlutterNativeSplash.remove();
  
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({required this.title, super.key});
  final String title;

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> with WidgetsBindingObserver { 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);   
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      title: widget.title,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false, 
    
    );
  } 
  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
 
    authRepository.dispose(); 
  }
}
```

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> with UIMixin {
  final AppNavigator appNavigator = sl<AppNavigator>();
  final RouteCubit routeCubit = sl<RouteCubit>();  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); 
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<RouteCubit, RouteState>(
      bloc: routeCubit,
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is RouteTarget) {
          if (state.name == AppPages.home) {
            appNavigator.goToHome(context);
          } else if (state.name == AppPages.signUp) {
            appNavigator.goToSignUp(context);
          }
        }
        if (state is RouteError) { 
           //ALERT
          );
        }
      },
      child: Scaffold(
```

I am debugging my code, and actually, I see that the state is correct. This is my navigator class.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import '../../data/data.dart';
import '../../injection.dart';
import '../config.dart';

class AppNavigator {
  void back<T>(BuildContext context, {T? result}) {
    if (canPop(context)) {
      Navigator.of(context).pop(result);
    }
  }

  bool canPop(BuildContext context) => Navigator.of(context).canPop();
 
  void goToHome(BuildContext context) { 
    context.pushReplacementNamed(AppPages.home);
  } 
  void goToSplash(BuildContext context) { 
    _removeAllPage(context);
    context.pushReplacementNamed(AppPages.splash);
  }
 
  void goToSignUp(BuildContext context) {
    context.pushReplacementNamed(AppPages.home);
  }
 

  void _removeAllPage(BuildContext context) {
    while (context.canPop()) {
      context.pop();
    }
  } 
}
```

If we look at the routes, this is my route class where I defined the routes and added an observer. By the way, it goes wherever I set as the InitialLocation. I can see from the logs that the observer is triggered when the splash screen first runs. I am also adding my observer class.

Routes.dart:

```
abstract class AppRoutes {
  static GoRouter get router => GoRouter(
        initialLocation: "/${AppPages.splash}",
        routes: [
          GoRoute(
              path: "/${AppPages.splash}",
              name: AppPages.splash,
              builder: (context, state) => const SplashScreen(),
            ),
          GoRoute(
            path: "/${AppPages.home}",
            name: AppPages.home,
            builder: (context, state) => const HomeScreen(),
          ),
          GoRoute(
            path: "/${AppPages.signUp}",
            name: AppPages.signUp,
            builder: (context, state) => const SignUpScreen(),
          ),
        ],
        observers: [
          AppNavigatorObserver(),
        ],
      );
}
```

Observer.dart:

```
 
class AppBlocObserver extends BlocObserver {
  @override
  void onChange(BlocBase<dynamic> bloc, Change<dynamic> change) {
    super.onChange(bloc, change);
    final blocType = bloc.runtimeType;
    final changeType = change.runtimeType;

    if (blocType == LanguageBloc && changeType == Change<LanguageState>) {
      _onLanguageChanged(change as Change<LanguageState>);
    }
  }

  @override
  void onError(BlocBase<dynamic> bloc, Object error, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    super.onError(bloc, error, stackTrace);
  }

  void _onLanguageChanged(Change<LanguageState> change) {
    if (change.nextState is LanguageSelected) {
     }
  }
}

class AppNavigatorObserver extends NavigatorObserver {
  final AppSystemOverlay _appSystemOverlay = sl<AppSystemOverlay>();
  final Logger _logger = Logger("App Navigator Observer");

  @override
  void didPush(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    String? routeName = route.settings.name;
    String? prevRouteName = previousRoute?.settings.name;

    _logger.info("didPush() {routeName:$routeName, prevRouteName:$prevRouteName}");
    if (routeName == AppPages.splash) {
      _appSystemOverlay.setSystemUIOverlayStyleForSplash();
    } else {
      _appSystemOverlay.setSystemUIOverlayStyle();
    }
  }

  @override
  void didPop(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    String? routeName = route.settings.name;
    String? prevRouteName = previousRoute?.settings.name;

    _logger
        .info("didPop() {routeName:$routeName, prevRouteName:$prevRouteName}");
 
  }

  @override
  void didRemove(Route<dynamic> route, Route<dynamic>? previousRoute) {
    String? routeName = route.settings.name;
    String? prevRouteName = previousRoute?.settings.name;

    _logger.info(
        "didRemove() {routeName:$routeName, prevRouteName:$prevRouteName}");

    if (routeName == AppPages.splash) {
      _appSystemOverlay.setSystemUIOverlayStyle();
    }
  }

  @override
  void didReplace({Route<dynamic>? newRoute, Route<dynamic>? oldRoute}) {
    String? newRouteName = newRoute?.settings.name;
    String? oldRouteName = oldRoute?.settings.name;

    _logger.info(
        "didReplace() {newRouteName:$newRouteName, oldRouteName:$oldRouteName}");
  }
}
```

I am getting the first log as "INFO "App Navigator Observer" : didPush() {routeName:splash, prevRouteName:null} " but then never triggered observer class.

How can I overcome this issue?
Note: I haven't shared the Cubit classes since I observed that the state is correctly received during debugging.

I have tried to debug the application and observed that the state is correctly received in the specified Bloc. I also examined the route configurations and observer class. Despite these efforts, the application seems to get stuck on the splash screen.

I was expecting that the splash screen would trigger the observer, and upon receiving the expected state, the application would smoothly navigate to the specified route. However, the actual behavior indicates a problem that I am currently trying to identify and resolve.